# uninitialized constant [ControllerName] with basic search bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, search

I'm trying to add search to my site and when I type something in I get a routing error. The search bar is in the nav. I assume it's something with the controller?

ERROR

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant ProfileController
```

Controller

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
  end

  def show
          @profiles = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end
```

HTML

```
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li id="logo"><%= link_to "Pallet",   '/' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Home",   '/' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Help",   '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Log in", '#' %></li>
           <li> <%= link_to 'New Profile', new_profile_path %></li>
            <li> <%= link_to 'Search', profiles_path %>           
        <%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>


 <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
              </ul>
            </nav>
```

Routes

```
get '/search(.:format)' => 'profile#show'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your route that doesn't use the convention of plural for a controller.

Change it to...

```
get '/search(.:format)' => 'profiles#show'
```

Even better, do...

```
get '/search(.:format)' => 'profiles#index'
```

And make your index method...

```
def index
  if params[:q]
    @profiles = Profile.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:q]}%")
  else
    @profiles = Profile.all
  end
end
```

You would then use the `show` method just to show a specific record, which is what it really was intended for.

Comment: so when i do that i get this error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProfilesController#show. Couldn't find Profile with 'id'=` and the code that comes up is `def set_profile @profile = Profile.find(params[:id]) end`

Comment: Yeah, but that's a different problem.  What do you want to do with the search term that's returned   Is it something in a column in profiles?  Maybe the profile `name`?

Comment: And how do you want to display the profile?  You'd be better off having the search direct to `profiles#index`

Comment: got it. just trying to search for something like a job and then return the profiles that match it. i.e. "actor"

Comment: thanks. still not working for me. but thanks for your help. i wonder if it matters that the search bar is in the application.html not index.html

Comment: here's the full error `ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial profiles/_profile with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:era, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.`

Comment: Well, we solved your first problem, so that's good.  If you have further questions you may want to post a different question, or get a tutorial or other advice on developing Ruby applications.  I can recommend "Agile Web Development with Rails 4" by Sam Ruby, Dave Thomas, and DHH.  You can find it on Amazon.

Comment: Did you post the entire view? Note that the `show` method will (by default) render a show.html.  You don't specify what your html is called.  Anyway, as mentioned, this is now fodder for a new question.

Answer (score 1):

There's a discrepancy between

```
ProfileController
```

And

```
ProfilesController
```

Since your route goes to 'profile' controller drop the 's' in that class name declaration. And possibly the file name too

Or alternatively you can change your route to this

```
get '/search(.:format)' => 'profiles#show'
```

Comment: Updated my answer to say where @rs19

Comment: thanks. so when i do that see what i commented happens on the answer below. it pulls up a new error.

Comment: That's a different error. This answer got you past the error you were on though so would appreciate an upvote :)

Comment: Ps your new error just says you can't find a record without an id. According to your route you would call it like this in ur url ... "/search?id=123"   <-where 123 is a valid profile record id

Answer (score 1):

To add to `@SteveTurcyzn`'s answer, you'll be better using the following in your `routes`:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :profiles, path: "search", only: [:index] #-> url.com/search
```

You'll then be able to use:

```
#app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
     before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

     def index
        # Use steve's answer here
     end

end
```

Comment: thanks for this. any idea what a good resource is on how to now render these results in a view?

Comment: I can tell you how to do it if you give me some context. You're looking to render the `index` for `search` - do you want to run a search of the `profiles`?